# CMSMS nice urls

Tags: mod-rewrite

I am using CMSMS for a work project and haven't much experience with it myself.  I have a videos page which lists every video by category.  Each video links to:

/newsandresources/single-video-page/&referenceId=networks

where 'networks' is replaced with a reference ID attached to the video.  What I need to do is create a mod_rewrite rule to re-direct:

/newsandresources/know-your-audience

(or whichever reference ID) to the single video's page and pass the reference ID

/newsandresources/single-video-page/&referenceId=know-your-audience

Does that make sense? :-/  sorry if not.  I've come up with the follow mod_rewite code so far:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^newsandresources/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/$ /newsandresources/single-video-page/&referenceId=$1
RewriteRule ^newsandresources/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ /newsandresources/single-video-page/&referenceId=$1
```

unfortunately it's not working.  wondering if thee's anyone out there able to help?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
RewriteRule ^\/newsandresources\/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+) /newsandresources/single-video-page/&referenceId=$1
```